# WPF DataBinding Bing Maps wpf api

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

I have spent countless hours reading and researching this topic – and I just can’t seem to get a foothold on it. Here is my scenario:

I write software for a company that provides asset-tracking (with some added features).  We currently have an ASP.NET based website using the googlemaps api. So this is what I am comfortable with.

I have now been tasked with writing a WPF application with much of the same functionality but instead using the wpf bing maps api. 
I have messed around with the map and figured out (non-mvvm way) how to draw custom pushpins, polygons, etc… Now I need to use the databinding features. This is where I just can’t seem to put the two together. Basically what I am trying to do is bind a collection of a custom class that creates a custom pushpin, to a MapControlItem.

The documentation is just a bit too fragmented and abstract for me to grab on to something – or maybe I am just too much of a web developer and really struggling to grasp a concept that is new to me.

Any ideas? Examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, the Bing Maps WPF Control API documentation is a joke.

Anyway, you would have to use a [`MapItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.mapitemscontrol.aspx) and bind its [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property to your item collection. The [`ItemsContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) and/or [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) properties would define the UI objects that are shown on the map.

You may start reading about [Data Binding to Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections).

Comment: You may also have a look at the sample WPF application in [XAML Map Control](https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/), which also has a MapItemsControl. The sample application shows how to use it.

Comment: Thanks.. this pointed me in the right direction. I need to spend some time, working with basic examples of binding to collections first. Then move on to the map.

Answer (score 0):

I only played with the Windows 8 version of the Bing maps control, not the WPF one, so I apologize if my answer is not quite apropriate.

What I know, is that in windows 8, you just can't apply bindings, for MapLayers or MapChildren.
From what you describe, I believe you just can't do a binding on these properties in WPF, simply because they are not dependency properties.

So only 1 solution left, in you window's code-behind, subscribe to your ViewModel's PropertyChanged event, and manually apply any updates you need to your control.

Anoter way to do that, is to create a UserControl, which will simply display a BingMaps control, and add to this userControl a "BingMapsContext" (or whatever) dependency property, to manually update the map control when that specific property will be binded.